# Angular package with NPM and GIT: dist folder in the repo?

Tags: angular, git, npm, npm-install, angular-module

### What I want to achieve:

I've created an Angular module and I want to `npm install` it from my GIT repo (I don't want to use `npm publish`, because it is a private code) in other projects.

I'm using `ng-packagr` (https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr) to get Angular Package Format. This creates a `dist` folder to the newly created package.

This is how I install mypackage with GIT for example:

```
npm install https://SOMETHING/SOMETHING.git#v0.1.0
```

### What my problem is:

My problem is that I've tried these two thing, but both of them are ugly or bad, I think:

1. I pushed **everything** to my GIT repo (I removed `dist` from `.gitignore`), but after `npm install` and `npm start` I get a module not find error. I don't think that this even works, because the package is in the subfolder `dist` (I import my module from `node_modules/mypackage/dist`). The other problem is that when I install the package, my source files are there too, and that is not the best.
2. I pushed only the `dist` folder to the GIT repo. Then I can install it easily in another project, and it works, there are no errors. But my problem with this is that I should push my code somewhere else too. With this I have to have 2 GIT repos. One for my actual code, and one for the package (`dist` folder).

I know there has to be some kind of better solution. I read a lot of articles, but I found nothing.

Can anyone suggest a good solution for this? Or should I go with the second one?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Could please anyone help with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that if you really want to install it from a git repository you'll have to have 2 repos.
I recently had to migrate a similar project and we used a **private npm registry**. The idea is to host your own packages into your private npm registry so only users with the correct credentials can install your packages. We used [Azure artifacts](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/artifacts/) because the user was already using Azure but AFAIK it has some free tier and is really easy to setup.

Answer (score 0):

you can push it with a different scope on your npm registry.